# Atualizando status do pagamento usando Cron no laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cron

Tenho o seguinte cenário: estou utilizando uma api de pagamentos aonde cada ordem expira em 15 minutos, como posso registrar uma tarefa cron para cada ordem de pagamento que tenho, mau sei por onde começar estou utilizando laravel 8.

Answer (score 1):

O caminho é implementar um comando artisan na sua aplicação que ao ser executado expire os pagamentos, digamos que o nome dele seja `expirar-pagamentos`

Depois você cria uma entrada no schedule no arquivo `App\Console\Kernel`, dentro do método `protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)` você vai fazer a chamada deste comando, o ideal a cada 1 minuto, a lógica do comando é que deve analisar se já passaram 15 min da ordem de pagamento.

Exemplo:

```php
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * demais código da classe
     */

    ... 

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('expirar-pagamentos')->everyMinute();
    }
}
```

Por fim deve adicionar a linha de chamada do comando agendador do seu projeto Laravel no cron do sistema

```
* * * * * cd /caminho-do-seu-projeto && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Para adicionar esta linha no cron você pode usar o comando `crontab -e` para abrir o editor de linha de comando do arquivo cron.

Answer (score -2):

A pergunta está bem generalizada, porém o que você quer fazer no laravel chama-se Task Scheduling. A documentação de como usar está abaixo:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling

mas creio que tu teria que criar um script e executar dessa forma:

$schedule->exec('node /home/forge/script.js')->tempo()*;

- primeiro seria a cada 5 minutos, segundo a cada 10 e terceiro a cada 15 minutos
  ->everyFiveMinutes();   Run the task every five minutes
  ->everyTenMinutes();    Run the task every ten minutes
  ->everyFifteenMinutes();    Run the task every fifteen minutes